# What is the standard convention to distinguish Protractor and Karma test files?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, protractor

I'm setting up Karma and Protractor tests for the first time.  Following [John Papa's style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#testing), unit test files are alongside the files they're testing, so for example: `login.controller.js, login.controller.spec.js`

However, if I'm adding a protractor test file I'd want to call it something like `login.spec.js`.  (this is all for the login module)

What is the standard convention for naming to distinguish which test files are Karma unit tests and which are Protractor e2e tests?

Answer (score 2):

It is not about actual file names - it is about *where your specs are located*.

It is a good idea to have your unit tests right near the actual code they are testing and related to, make them close to the "unit" under test, cause, these are unit tests.

On the other hand, end-to-end tests are entities of a much higher level of abstraction - e2e spec files should be located away from the actual code, in a special directory. Personally, I like the idea to have a "test" folder under the project root. This is a directory structure we've agreed to have inside the team (simplified):

```
- root
    - src
        - components
            - header
                header-controller.js
                header-controller_test.js
    - test
        - e2e
            - config
                local.conf.js
                remote.conf.js
            - specs
                - screen1
                    screen1.blabla.spec.js
            - po
                screen1.po.js
        karma.local.conf.js
        karma.remote.conf.js
```

Where `specs` directory contains all of the end-to-end spec files, while `po` - page objects for every page, or part of a page of the application.

Comment: Moving them away makes sense as they relate to more than one area, and I like how you have some logical distinction between types of tests, though what other folder besides e2e would you have under test if unit tests live next to the code they relate to?

Comment: @John thank you, we usually add `_test` prefix to unit tests and place them right next to the js files under test, I've added an example to the project structure. Hope this is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite opinion based but I think deserving of an answer as I have had a similar issue in the past.

From my experience, I have used the same `login.spec.js` but inside an e2e folder at the root.

The reason being although in this instance you *might* be running an end to end test for the login module, as a general rule the end to end tests will be running integration style tests across multiple controllers/services/views. The nature of these tests make them difficult to keep to a one-to-one file relationship like you may do with the unit tests.

eg There is no reason why you may not also have a protractor test that logs in, then changes some details on an account, then logs out.

In this situation, the e2e test wouldn't make sense to live in either the account or login module directories.

Comment: That's an important distinction that I hadn't quite realized yet ... while I will have some tests within a module that are e2e, many will be cross-module and thus won't fit into the normal folder hierarchy ... thanks for raising that point.